# SQL - Get results from table 1 but count all matching results from 2, 3 & 4

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to print a list of 20 online blog articles, along with the count of comments, photos and videos for each article. They all share the `article_id` field but not every article has a comment, a photo or a video.

**My working query so far:** (without the counts)

```
SELECT a.article_id, a.title, a.published, a.description, a.status, ad.firstname, ad.lastname FROM blog_articles AS a
LEFT JOIN admins AS ad ON a.author_id = ad.admin_id *** grabs article author
WHERE a.status = 'Online' ORDER BY a.published DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

**My attempt** (with the counts)

```
SELECT COUNT(comment_id) AS tot_comments, COUNT(photo_id) AS tot_photos,
COUNT(video_id) AS tot_videos, a.article_id, a.title, a.published, a.description,
a.status, ad.firstname, ad.lastname
FROM blog_articles AS a
LEFT JOIN blog_comments AS ac USING (article_id)
LEFT JOIN photos AS p USING (article_id)
LEFT JOIN videos AS v USING (article_id)
LEFT JOIN admins AS ad ON a.author_id = ad.admin_id
WHERE a.status = 'Online'
GROUP BY a.article_id
ORDER BY a.published DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

But this is acting strangely. I'm getting the correct articles and textual data, but the counts are reeeeeeeally off! If an article really has 18 comments, 0 photos and 1 video, my displayed results say 18 comments, 0 photos and 18 videos. If an article has 0 comments, 6 photos and 1 video, my results sat 0 comments, 6 photos and 6 videos!

I'm close to getting it working, my joining knowledge is rusty, my brain hurts, please can somebody put me out of misery and kick me over the finish line? I can see what is happening, but I can't work out how to solve it.

This is what I want to display for each record in my `blog_articles` table:

**Article Title:** This is the title | **Comments:** 42 | **Photos:** 20 | **Videos:** 2

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović: Thanks for your attempt and thanks for pointing out that Stenerson's answer was a better performing version :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best bet is going to be derived tables

```
SELECT a.title, c.cnt as comments, p.cnt as photos, v.cnt as videos
  FROM blog_articles a
 INNER JOIN admins ad
    ON a.author_id = ad.admin_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT article_id, COUNT(comment_id) as cnt
     FROM blog_comments
    GROUP BY article_id) c
    ON a.article_id = c.article_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT article_id, COUNT(photo_id) as cnt
     FROM photos
    GROUP BY article_id) p
    ON a.article_id = p.article_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT article_id, COUNT(video_id) as cnt
     FROM videos
    GROUP BY article_id) v
    ON a.article_id = v.article_id
 WHERE a.status = 'Online'
GROUP BY a.article_id
ORDER BY a.published DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

---

Just because I couldn't let it go, check out [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb2be/4) that shows the execution plans and times of both the derived table and count distinct options.  Both provide the same data but in this example derived tables are 0ms compared to 1ms for the counts.  It would be interesting to see these queries executed with some real data but in my experience derived tables yield performance that count cannot.

Comment: Looks like I'm a couple minutes late to the game.  I think this will work but if simply using `COUNT(distinct xx)` works I may have over complicated it.  Happy SQLing.

Comment: +1 from me. This is more to the point and - in my opinion - the way to go whenever one aggregates over multiple tables to avoid possibility of duplicating results.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks @NikolaMarkovinović. I'm going to try and understand it and then try implementing it.

Comment: @MartinG I couldn't move on with my night unless I knew for sure.  Check out the SQL Fiddle that I added in the answer.  Enjoy!

Comment: @Stenerson: Well now you can move on with your night, knowing you're the daddy! It worked a treat and I kind of understand it too. It's really interesting to see the two compared. Thanks a bunch. I'd +10 if I could...

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried this, but please try

```
SELECT COUNT(comment_id) AS tot_comments, COUNT(photo_id) AS tot_photos,
COUNT(video_id) AS tot_videos, a.article_id, a.title, a.published, a.description,
a.status, ad.firstname, ad.lastname
FROM blog_articles AS a
LEFT JOIN blog_comments AS ac ON ac.article_id = a.article_id
LEFT JOIN photos AS p ON p.article_id = a.article_id
LEFT JOIN videos AS v ON v.article_id = a.article_id
LEFT JOIN admins AS ad ON a.author_id = ad.admin_id
WHERE a.status = 'Online'
GROUP BY a.article_id
ORDER BY a.published DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```